# Controlling line height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to style an HTML listing with Bootstrap 5.
My problem is achieving a proper line height. The `.lh` class in bootstrap even with `.lh-1` is too high. The negative margin doesn't seem to work for me. Any ideas?

I achieved the designed look but using *small* but I would prefer it to be a *p*, as it's important data.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">


  <!-- LISTING 1-->
  <section id="listing_ad" class="px-3  lh-1 pb-4">

    <div id="row_1" class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <img class="w-100" src="user_listing_images/sm-square/hans.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">

        <!-- LISTING ROW 1 -->

        <div id="row_1" class="">
          <h3 class="text-white fw-light font-monospace">How it is</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- LISTING ROW 2 -->

        <div id="row_2" class="row">
          <div class=" col-3">
            <p class="text-white small   font-monospace">5 days</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <p class="text-white small   font-monospace">$700</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <p class="text-white small   font-monospace">26.05.2023</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- LISTING ROW 3 -->

        <div id="row_2" class="row">
          <div id="user_rating" class="col-sm-3">
            <p class="text-white small  font-monospace"><i class="bi bi-heart"></i> 4.9</p>
          </div>
          <div id="user_from" class="col-sm-3">
            <p class="text-white small  font-monospace"><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i> 124</p>
          </div>
          <div id="user_from" class="col-sm-3">
            <p class="text-white small  font-monospace"><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-down"></i> 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- LISTING ROW 3 -->

        <div id="row_3" class="row">
          <div id=" user_from" class="col-sm-7">
            <p class="text-white small  font-monospace">by Jorge Martiges</p>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

  </section>


  <!-- LISTING 2-->
  <section id="listing_ad" class="px-3 pb-4">

    <div id="row_1" class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <img class="w-100" src="user_listing_images/sm-square/thayran.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">

        <!-- LISTING ROW 1 -->

        <div id="row_2" class="row lh-basic">
          <h3 class="text-white fw-light font-monospace">How I want it</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- LISTING ROW 2 -->

        <div id="row_2" class="row lh-basic">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <small class="text-white   font-monospace">10 day</small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <small class="text-white   font-monospace">$3999</small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <small class="text-white   font-monospace">20.05.2023</small>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- LISTING ROW 3 -->

        <div id="row_2" class="row lh-basic">
          <div id="user_rating" class="col-sm-3">
            <small class="text-white  font-monospace"><i class="bi bi-heart"></i> New</small>
          </div>
          <div id="user_from" class="col-sm-3">
            <small class="text-white  font-monospace"><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i> New</small>
          </div>
          <div id="user_from" class="col-sm-3">
            <small class="text-white  font-monospace"><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-down"></i> New</small>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- LISTING ROW 3 -->

        <div id="row_3" class="row lh-basic">
          <div id="user_from" class="col-sm-7">
            <small class="text-white  font-monospace">by Tribu de las Aguas</small>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- END OF LISTINGS -->
  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```